# xcode can't find a standard c++ include file

Tags: iphone, xcode, project

When i mix .m and .cpp i have a problem with xcode not finding the default cpp include (like `<map>`)

update:
i'm adding a static lib in my iphone project (which does compile without any problems) and then use the include inside the .m, then the dependencies .h from c++ gets crazy..can't find or can't compile, i tried the .mm but it does'nt works.

Comment: Please give more information about your project and Xcode version. My Xcode (gcc) does find everything as expected.

Comment: You will have to be more specific to get a useful answer—I can only guess at an answer. Please show us the code in question and be clear about the extension used on the source files.

Comment: xcode 3.1.3 with a static lib in an iphone app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Objective-C++ (i.e. mixing Objective-C and C++ in one source file or importing a C++ header into an Objective-C file), then you should be using the `.mm` extension on your source code files. By default, Xcode will compile `.mm` files using the Objective-C++ compiler. `.m` files are compiled using the standard C compiler.

Comment: Good addition to this is that **any** implementation file that imports anything that's compiled by the C++-compiler has to use `.mm` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to diagnose this is to drag the "Compiling foo.mm" line from your Build Results window into a reply to this message. That shows us what your project is telling the compiler, in excruciating detail, and will show exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Line Location c++config.h:153: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'std'

Comment: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/usr/include/libkern/OSByteOrder.h:92: error: 'uint16_t' does not name a type

Comment: Please provide the line that starts with "Compiling" so we can see the *input*, not just the *output*.